# What does the reordering field of ss --info mean?

Tags: networking, tcp, netstat, ss

`ss --info` returns information about tcp connections. It produces a line simliar to the following (some fields removed for formatting)

`tcp  ESTAB    0    0      192.168.1.177:60236      54.70.141.88:https
    cubic wscale:7,7 rto:204 rtt:0.918/0.419 reordering:59`

What exactly does the `reordering` number mean in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [TCP Variables](https://www.frozentux.net/ipsysctl-tutorial/chunkyhtml/tcpvariables.html):

> The tcp_reordering variable tells the kernel how much a TCP packet may
>   be reordered in a stream without assuming that the packet was lost
>   somewhere on the way.

`tcp_reordering` may be changed via `net.ipv4.tcp_reordering` variable of `sysctl`. By default this value is `3`.

If you change `net.ipv4.tcp_reordering` variable, then `ss --info` will print all connections with values which are differs from `3`. [Fragment of `iproute2` source](https://github.com/CumulusNetworks/iproute2/blob/6335c5ff67202cf5b39eb929e2a0a5bb133627ba/misc/ss.c#L1980):

```
. . .
if (s->reordering != 3)
        printf(" reordering:%d", s->reordering);
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's really useful.

Comment: @timlyo You are welcome!